SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (_ssl.c:1000) and (_ssl.c:1006)
I'm encountering an SSL handshake failure when upgrading my Python application from versions 3.8 and 3.9 to 3.11 or 3.12.
Python 3.12: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1000)
Python 3.11: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1006)
The server side uses TLS 1.2 and python 3.11 or 3.12 Trying to use SSLV3
I suspect this is due to a mismatch between the server and client protocols.
Below is a snippet of my code:
import http.client
import ssl


host = "xyzabcd.com"  #
path = "/getFileDetails"   
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "MyApp", 
    "Authorization": "Bearer token"  
}

# Initialize HTTPSConnection with SSL context
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host)

# Send the GET request with custom headers
try:
    conn.request(method="GET", url=path, headers=headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print("Status:", response.status)
    print("Reason:", response.reason)
    print("Headers:", response.getheaders())
    data = response.read()
    print("Body:", data.decode("utf-8")) 
except ssl.SSLError as e:
    print("SSL Error:", e)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e)
finally:
    conn.close()

I tried following to enforce python 3.11 code to use TLS
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
import ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
context.maximum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host , context=context)


"Trying to use SSLV3 I " - please don't be irritated by the SSL error claiming "sslv3". You get also the same error code with TLS 1.2 etc. This is just because TLS 1.2 and SSLv3 share many things, including the alert codes. Unfortunately such handshake errors can be basically anything and it is impossible to figure out w/o details and ideally a way to reproduce it using the specific server. But my guess is that your server is too old and uses insecure/obsolete ciphers, protocol versions or certificates. For example it might be that your server does not support TLS 1.2 yet.

My server using TLS 1.2

You can use the free online tool at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to get all kinds of details about what your server accepts for the many parameter choices in the different parts of the SSL/TLS protocol.

Issue fixed after setting cipher context to supported server protocol
did following
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.set_ciphers(‘@SECLEVEL=2:ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+CHACHA20:ECDH+AES:DHE+AES:AESGCM:!aNULL:!eNULL:!aDSS:!SHA1:!AESCCM:!PSK’)
